# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=1

Tags: android

I am doing messaging platform.Msgdesc is my message but somebody send message ,somebody dont.So ı have some date in msgdesc.if ı havent exist any data ı want to do nothing but if i want i want to see also msgdesc with name+surname.But i am getting **java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=1**
Can anybody help me?

Code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < midArr.length; i++) {
    //getting desc from db
    getMessagedbXML = messagedbInstance.getMessages(mid,midArr[i]);             
    parseXMLDB(getMessagedbXML);
    UserList=new String[midArr.length];
    **//getting error here**    
    if((msgdesc[i].length()==0)) {
        UserList[i] = nameArr[i]+" "+surnameArr[i];
    } else {
        UserList[i] = nameArr[i]+" "+surnameArr[i]+" "+msgdesc[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the error? Post the whole stack trace.

Comment: I am getting error here :if((msgdesc[i].length()==0)) {

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to this?

```
if(msgdesc.length() == 0 || msgdesc[i].length() == 0)
```

*(don't know what of type `msgdesc` is)*

Answer (score 2):

my guess would be that you're using the wrong variable (msgdesc).

Or rather, you're using the wrong test.

Use

```
if (msgdesc.length()!=0 && msgdesc[i].length()!=0))
```

instead of

```
if (msgdesc[i].length()!=0))
```